# fish in a pool, when mouse is near must go away

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i'd like to make something like a fish pool.
when no action is happening, animated fish goes around.
when mouse go near that, they go away from the mouse.
i think it has been done many times, but i'm not able to find tutorials that explain this problem.
i'm looking for a tutorial
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

( this is not a trivial problem at all )

hi,

this kind of motion is called *flocking*. there are fairly simple rules to put together and your *boids* will become autonomous. the original concept of *boids* was found and developed by [Craig Reynolds](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/index.html) and is available here: http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/.

explainations and an implementation in actionscript were done by [Keith Peters](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/) in his book AdvncED actionscript 3.0.

the chapter concerning flocking is available here: http://books.google.fr/books?id=QuwsOHYA0p4C&pg=PA92&lpg=PA93&vq=flocking#v=onepage&q=flocking&f=false

and the material ( classes and samples files ) are available here: http://www.friendsofed.com/download.html?isbn=1430216085

note that other implementations exist, I'd recommend this one http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=231

you might also be interested in grant skinner's wander motion class: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/11/wander_motion_c.html

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how elaborate the fish's movement is, you have to measure the distance and angle between the fish and the mouse position on `Event.ENTER_FRAME` (or at a `Timer` interval), then have the fish move in the opposite direction, if the distance is less than the minimum value.

These might help:

```
function getDistance ( posa:Point, posb:Point ) : Number {
    var distanceX : Number = posa.x - posb.x;
    var distanceY : Number = posa.y - posb.y;
    return Math.sqrt( Math.pow(distanceX, 2) + Math.pow (distanceY, 2) );
}

function getAngle ( posa:Point, posb:Point ) : Number {
    var distanceX : Number = posa.x - posb.x;
    var distanceY : Number = posa.y - posb.y;
    var angleInRadians : Number = Math.atan2 ( distanceY, distanceX );
    var angleInDegrees : Number = angleInRadians * (180 / Math.PI);
    return angleInDegrees > 0 ? angleInDegrees : angleInDegrees + 360; // always returns a positive value to avoid confusion when used with the rotation property
}
```

usage:

```
var posa:Point = fish.parent.localToGlobal (new Point (fish.x, fish.y);  // fish position relative to the stage
var posb:Point = new Point (stage.mouseX, stage.mouseY);                 // mouse position relative to the stage
var distance:Number = getDistance (posa, posb);                          // distance in pixels
var angle:Number = getAngle (posa, posb);                                // angle in degrees
```